# converting json -(utf-8) to json(unicode escape) & raw strings(cant have odd number of backlash)

Tags: python, json, unicode, encoding, utf-8

Hi I have some trouble in converting utf-8 json to unicode escape json in Python

I know how to convert utf-8.txt to unicode escape.txt

```
with open("input.txt", "r", encoding='utf8') as f:
    text = f.read()

with open('output.txt', 'w', encoding='unicode-escape') as f:
    f.write(text)
```

However, I face the issues applying above with the json module in python like below

```
with codecs.open(self.input,'r', encoding='utf-8') as json_file:
    json_data = json.load(json_file)

with codecs.open(self.output,'w', encoding='unicode-escape') as json_file:
    prepare_json = json.dumps(json_data, ensure_ascii=False)
    json_file.write(prepare_json)
```

it saves fine but, when it comes to double quotation (") in the json, it automatically add double backslashes(\\), so unicode-escape.json file is not working properly when calling in python script.

Suppose

```
1. Input file (UTF-8): {"context" : "-\" 너"}
```

And I convert it via second code block above

```
2. Output file (UNICODE-ESCAPED) : {"context" : "-\\" \ub108"}
```

```
3. What I want (UNICODE-ESCAPED) : {"context" : "-\" \ub108"}
```

Since it has double backslashes in front of double quotation, Python shows error when loading unicode-escaped json file.

More details

Input file : ./simple_test.json

```
{"context" : "-\" 너"}
```

```
with codecs.open('./simple_test.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as json_file:
    json_data = json.load(json_file)

prepare_json = json.dumps(json_data, ensure_ascii=False)
prepare_json
>>> '{"context": "-\\" 너"}'
repr(prepare_json)
>>> '\'{"context": "-\\\\" 너"}\''
print(prepare_json)
>>> {"context": "-\" 너"}
```

So it should print out {"context": "-" \ub108"}
, which is just {"context": "-" 너"}.

```
Output.json(I excpected}
{"context": "-\" \ub108"}
```

However, with the code below i GOT

```
with codecs.open('./simple_test_out.json','w', encoding='unicode-escape') as json_file:
    json_file.write(prepare_json)
```

```
Output.json
{"context": "-\\" \ub108"}
```

With several attempts I figured it out *This happens only when writing file with encoding = "unicode-escape" format.*
and replace raw strings with the odd number of back slashes won't work.

Any suggestions or ideas would be appreciated!

#### More info

```
import codecs
import json

with codecs.open('./simple_test.json','r', encoding='utf-8') as json_file:
    json_data = json.load(json_file)

with codecs.open('.=simple_test_out.json','w', encoding='utf-8') as json_file:
    prepare_json = json.dumps(json_data, ensure_ascii=False)
    json_file.write(prepare_json)
```

this just works fine.

```
import codecs
import json

with codecs.open('./simple_test.json','r', encoding='utf-8') as json_file:
    json_data = json.load(json_file)

with codecs.open('.=simple_test_out.json','w', encoding='unicode-escape') as json_file:
    prepare_json = json.dumps(json_data, ensure_ascii=False)
    json_file.write(prepare_json)
```

but this won't work and it is the format i want

Comment: trying to convert utf-8 encoding json file to unicode-escaped json file.

Comment: Oh if your question is why converting utf-8 encoding json file to unicode-escaped json file, I need to save this json files with unicode-escaped json format

Comment: Are you aware that the REPL implicitly calls `repr` on its outputs? So you see more backslashes than there really are. Inspect the string values with `print()` instead.

Comment: By default, `json.dump()` creates ASCII output, so saving it with UTF-8, ASCII, Latin-1 or unicode-escape should store the same byte sequence to disk (because they all work the same for the ASCII subset of characters).

Comment: @lenz Yeah I aware that REPL implicitly calls ```repr``` on  outputs like as I showed ```repr(prepare_json)``` above. Also ```print(prepare_json)``` as you mentioned and I showed above is the exact format I want to save in a json file.

Comment: @lenz But my problem is that json.dump() returns repr on the double quotation(").

Comment: The backslash doubling comes from the unicode-escape codec, not from `json.dump`. My second comment wasn't correct then: the unicode-escape codec isn't equivalent to ASCII, because of this backslash escaping. If you don't want this doubling (why would you anyway?), then don't use the unicode-escape codec. Just use ASCII – `json.dump` be default produces ASCII output, using escapes according to the JSON specs.

Comment: Ok, re-reading your edits, I think you know all that already. So what *does* the unicode-escape codec give you that UTF-8 or ASCII doesn't?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you just want `ensure_ascii=True` (the default):

```
C:\>type input.json
{"context" : "-\" 너"}

C:\>py
Python 3.8.1 (tags/v3.8.1:1b293b6, Dec 18 2019, 23:11:46) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import json
>>> with open('input.json',encoding='utf8') as f:
...    data = json.load(f)
...
>>> data
{'context': '-" 너'}
>>> with open('output.json','w',encoding='utf8') as f:
...    json.dump(data,f)
...
>>> ^Z

C:\>type output.json
{"context": "-\" \ub108"}
```

Comment: Thanks! It works. I was trying to manipulate raw strings. Now I learned setting ```encoding='unicode-escape ``` and ```ensure_ascii=False``` is different setting  ```ensure_ascii=False```! Thanks!